# Java 11 Generic Regex to parse a given String value

Tags: regex, parsing

I'm working on a side project for which I need to parse String to obtain substrings

I have a REST API containing a String parameter in the payload. This String value's pattern can vary across any of the enlisted patterns:

1. [Name]
2. [Name 1], [Name 2]
3. [Name 1] and [Name 2]
4. [Name 1], [Name 2] and [Name 3]
5. [Name 1], [Name 2] and [Name 3], [Role]

Options I tried:

- Including another parameter in the request payload that describes the format of the String value. For Ex: If a string value of pattern #4 is to be passed as input, here is the payload I would expect:

  {

  "Value" : "Name 1, Name 2 and Name 3",

  "Format": 4

  }

Here, it's a burden on the client to determine the format and set the format value accordingly, which is definitely not a good approach

- Somehow determine the format (For Ex: count the number of commas and AND keyword) and accordingly use a Reg-ex dedicated for that format
  For Ex: If the string contains at least one comma, an occurrence of the AND keyword and a comma after the AND keyword, it could be pattern #5 (described in the list above). So use the Reg-ex pattern: `([a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z]+)+),([a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z]+)+),[a-zA-Z]+`

   This approach does work, but still is far too rigid to be practical. For Ex: Consider 4 names (rather than 3) being a part of the value, the said pattern won't work

Is there a more generic reg-ex pattern possible that could satisfy each of the aforementioned patterns?

Comment: *"Is there a more generic reg-ex pattern possible that could satisfy each of the aforementioned patterns?"* - Seems to me that "and" serves the exact same purpose as the comma in your patterns. Replace `" and "` with comma, split the string on commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a generic regex pattern which covers all 5 types of inputs:

```regex
^\[.*?\](?:(?:,|\s+and\s+)\s*\[.*?\](?:\s+and\s+\[.*?\])*)*$
```

### Demo

Explanation of regex:

```regex
^                    start of string
\[.*?\]              match [Name]
(?:
    (?:,|\s+and\s+)  match either comma or "and" separator
    \s*              optional whitespace
    \[.*?\]          another [Name 2]
    (?:
        \s+and\s+    "and" separator
        \[.*?\]      more [Name] terms
    )*               zero or more
)*                   zero or more
$                    end of string
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write the pattern repeatedly matching all between the square brackets:

```
^\[[^\]\[]*](?:(?:,| and) \[[^\]\[]*])*$
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\[[^\]\[]*]` Match from `[....]`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:,| and)`  Match either a comma followed by a space or  `and` followed by a space
  - `\[[^\]\[]*]` Match from `[....]`
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ODtISm/1)

In Java with the doubled escaped backslashes:

```
String regex = "^\\[[^\\]\\[]*](?:(?:,| and) \\[[^\\]\\[]*])*$"
```